# Type guarding on boolean value in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a boolean variable (let's call it `isX`) and two functions (`getA` and `getB`) that return different types of array:

```
const isX: boolean; (value unknown at compilation time)
fn getA(): A[];
fn getB(): B[];
```

The function that is called depends on the boolean variable, following by some common logic that doesn't depend on type and then finally mapping the elements to components depending on the boolean variable value (either ComponentA or componentB)

```
const data: A[] | B[] = isX ? getA() : getB();
... custom logic common for both types of elements ...
return data.map(el => isX ? <ComponentA c={el} /> : <ComponentB c={el} />)
```

Last line gives me the following error:

```
Type 'A | B' is not assignable to type 'A'.
   Type 'B' is missing the following properties from type 'A': x, y, and 3 more.
```

What would be the best solution to solve this problem?

Comment: There is no way that typescript can infer the type of two unrelated objects. It can only infer when the two type belongs to the same object like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7VGrw)

Comment: In the `data.map` callback: instead of `isX ? …` you can use `"x" in el ? …`. If that addresses your question, I can write an answer explaining. If not, what did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

A popular concept for situations like yours is [Discriminated Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions). By runtime checking for a property in a [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) TypeScript can narrow the type to either `A` or `B`. Usually one uses a specific property that is available on all types of the union but technically it also works like this:

```
type A = {x: string};
type B = {y: string};

const ComponentA = (props: A) => 0;
const ComponentB = (props: B) => 0;

declare function getA(): A[];
declare function getB(): A[];
declare const isX: boolean;

let data: (A | B)[] = isX ? getA() : getB();

data.map(el => {
  if ("x" in el) { // <- We know that "x" is only available in type A
    return ComponentA(el);
  } else {
    return ComponentB(el);
  }
});
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAPAXFAzsATgSwDsBzAGigBM9MBjfAW0IEMDgNt9iBuAX04ChQkKACEEyEG1yFSUXnz7UA9gWxQAworphlEFnEQAKMDkVhMGGAEoEAPigAGfkpXB1m7QV3BRh46fMi1vB2jvLkENQANow40ABmAK4E1MB4ylBEEMAwBpYWANoAuvzhUTHxSSlpBBlZwrkFxXyl0bFQzqpUABoYAEaKipEQzPx8Q67kjMCMGAZwAD6BRWLdUAD8tdm5UBiZ3rmjk9MAdHSMYAYQkbbIfFBQeHFQBgBEKC8PNVfWSHf3ULFgAkcDUNFodHpLpFLPx7twoFdMNBfv8AVlgaD3BD9t9YbI%20NwYXwgA)